# Heroku - setting up a git environment for existing application

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Our developer recently got a new job, and I need to make some changes to our website. (Which is live).

However we don't have the computer that was used to push to our server. So I need to set it up on a new computer. However I can't find any guides related to already existing apps (at least from scratch).

I got the Heroku Toolbelt installed of course, and I can login correctly. (I am the owner of the application).

But I could really use some in-depth help to get a git-environment set up where I can pull from Heroku-master.

This is being done a new computer (windows), and there's no other tools than the Heroku Toolbelt installed atm.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried going into the application tab, and cloning the repository into a specific folder with the command they give you? (after using "heroku login")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Login** (command line)
2. **Clone repo** (into a new local directory)
3. **Commit/Pull/Push changes**

https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

```
$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: adam@example.com
Password (typing will be hidden):
Authentication successful.
```

Instructions to clone your repo (into a new folder) here:

https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/YOURAPPNAME/deploy/heroku-git

```
$ heroku git:clone -a YOURAPPNAME
$ cd YOURAPPNAME
```

(Remember to replace *YOURAPPNAME* with your application name - you can also navigate to it using the dashboard)

After that you should be able to commit any changes, push and pull requests.

Comment: That.. was a lot easier than I thought. (It took us 2 weeks to get this up and running in the first place).

Havn't tried pushing yet, but should be easy enough.

Thank you so incredibly much!